# Convert .net project 4.5 framework to windowsCE (smartDevice) project which supports development in 2008

Tags: windows-ce

I have written code in C# .net framework 4.5. Now, the client says he wants it in Windows CE. So I have downloaded VS 2008 and created a smart device project with Windows CE option and framework 3.5. I have used the files as is and build. The solution gives lots of error on build. 
Eg of error is - Background worker in .Net 4.5 is not supported in WinCE 2008 project
Any pointers how this can be achieved? Its a huge code so rewritting whole code will cost a lot. Quick pointers are highly appreciated.

I have tried removing the references from old proj and tried including dll from VS 2008 dlls. E.g. System.Data.SQL is not present in 2008. Background worker is not present in VS2008

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Smart Device Framework, it provides a port of the Background Worker for the .NET Compact Framework. It may give you some alternatives for other pieces of code you're porting over:

https://github.com/ctacke/sdf

The missing SQL Server library is a difficult one to answer without more details, but you will need to decide on how you wish to access data. Is there going to be a local database or will you need to retrieve data from the SQL Server database through some type of service?

SQL Server Compact and SQLite are popular databases used on Windows CE, so those are some options if you need to create some sort of local database.